# Setting the default document in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a web application running in IIS, 
which if I go to localhost:85 in my browser I get a 401 error saying '401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.'

If i go to localhost:85/default.aspx , it will redirect me to the log in page as expected.

How can I make it so that by default if I go to localhost:85 (the root directory) , it will take me to default.aspx automatically.

I tried setting the default Document in IIS to Default.aspx, but still it doesn't do what I was hoping it would.

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to to have iis automatically go to default.aspx if the user doesn't ask for a specific document?

Comment: Did you move default.aspx to the top of the list in default documents?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

After the default webpage is added, press the Move Up button until it's in first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as mentioned below.

> Go to IIS.
>
> Click on your Website.
>
> Select Default Document Option >> From the action pane click on add
>   button.
>
> It will open "Add Default Document" Dialog Box.
>
> Here, you can add default.aspx as your Default Document.

This is how you can set your Default document page.