# Windows authentication without a backend?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

We have a web application that runs on ASP.Net. I don't know much on authentication for ASP.Net, but the application never asks me for a username and password (when on a Windows machine) and that's really great. The app has this in the web.config file: `<authentication mode="Windows" />`.

I've been assigned the task to re-create this application. I noticed that the **only use** for the backend is to get the user's AD account username. After that, it makes some HTTP requests that require the username. Besides that, the back-end is useless. If that's the case, then is there a way for be to get the user's credentials without needing a back-end (ASP.Net server)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are going to create... If you aren't going to have a backend, then what *are* you going to have?

Comment: It's a static HTML website that gets data from other APIs. Technically, there would be backends, but I don't manage them. Other people made their own backend servers that have their own APIs that I call. But some of those APIs need to know the current logged-in user, which is what I would like to get without making my own backend.

Answer (score 0):

Really, a "backend" is anything on the server. You can't have a website without a web server, and that server is the "backend". It's always doing *some* kind of processing, even if it's not using ASP.NET.

But if I understand your requirements, you just want a way to inject the username into an otherwise static HTML file.

IIS handles the Windows Authentication, so you don't need ASP.NET to have Windows Authentication. But technically, static means static, so you can't modify an plain HTML file before it's served (unless you change stuff in IIS that would slow down *actually* static files).

But, the next best thing is to use a feature in IIS called [Server-Side Include Directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525185(v=vs.90)) (SSI). By default, IIS is setup to send files with extensions of `.stm`, `.stm`, and `.shtml` through its SSI engine, which processes the file and looks for specific "directives".

One of the features is the [`#echo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525581%28v%3dvs.90%29) directive, which lets you inject any IIS server variable into the content. If Windows Authentication is enabled and working, IIS stores the `DOMAIN\username` in the `LOGON_USER` server variable.

You can inject that into your page, and use JavaScript to split the domain and username into separate pieces. But you can't inject `LOGON_USER` directly into the JavaScript because of the slash, which JavaScript interprets as an escape character. So you have to put it in an HTML element, and use JS to pull it from there.

Here's an example of a simple page that stores the domain and username into JavaScript variables and displays them on the page. You'd have to save this file as `.stm`, `.stm`, or `.shtml`.

```
<html>
<body>
    <span id="domainUsername" style="display:none"><!-- #echo var = "LOGON_USER" --></span>
    Domain: <span id="domain"></span><br>
    Username: <span id="username"></span>
    <script>
        var domainUsername = document.getElementById("domainUsername").innerText.split("\\");
        var domain = domainUsername[0];
        var username = domainUsername[1];

        document.getElementById("domain").innerText = domain;
        document.getElementById("username").innerText = username;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And remember you still need `<authentication mode="Windows" />` in your web.config.

Then you can also [set that file as the Default Document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47774720/1202807) for your website (since IIS won't, by default, use a file with those extensions as the default doc).